# Toggle modal in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent container which has a couple of child components. When the user clicks `onClick={props.toggleReviewForm}`, the function

```
toggleReviewForm () {
   this.setState(prevState => ({
     reviewFormActive: !prevState.reviewFormActive,
     displayNameModalActive: !prevState.displayNameModalActive
    }))
}
```

toggles the reviewForm state to visible. It's visibility is set with `reviewFormActive={reviewFormActive}` in the child component and the parent has `this.state = {reviewFormActive: false} set in the constructor. I am passing

`displayNameModalActive={displayNameModalActive}`

into the child component for the modal, but getting the error

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayNameModalActive' of undefined at DisplayNameModal.render`

**Parent Container**

```
 class ReviewsContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      reviewFormActive: false,
      displayNameModalActive: false
    }
    this.config = this.props.config
    this.toggleReviewForm = this.toggleReviewForm.bind(this)
  }

  toggleReviewForm () {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      reviewFormActive: !prevState.reviewFormActive,
      displayNameModalActive: !prevState.displayNameModalActive
    }))
  }

  render () {
    const {
      reviewFormActive,
      displayNameModalActive
    } = this.state

    return (
      <div className='reviews-container'>
        <ReviewForm
          config={this.config}
          reviewFormActive={reviewFormActive}
          toggleReviewForm={this.toggleReviewForm}
        />

        {this.state.displayName &&
          <div className='modal-container'>
            <DisplayNameModal
              bgImgUrl={this.props.imageUrl('displaynamebg.png', 'w_1800')}
              config={this.config}
              displayNameModalActive={displayNameModalActive}
              displayName={this.state.displayName}
              email={this.state.email} />
          </div>
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ReviewsContainer
```

**Child Component (modal)**

```
 class DisplayNameModal extends React.Component {
  constructor (props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      displayName: this.props.displayName,
      email: this.props.email.split('@')[0]
    }
  }

  render (props) {
    const {contentStrings} = this.props.config

    return (
      <div>
      //Should only allow the modal to show if the username is the same as the email or there is no username available
      { props.displayNameModalActive && this.state.displayName === this.state.email || !this.state.displayName && 
      <div className='display-name-container' style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${this.props.bgImgUrl})` }}>
        <div className='display-name-content'>
          <h2 className='heading'>{contentStrings.displayNameModal.heading}</h2>
          <p>{contentStrings.displayNameModal.subHeading}</p>
          <input type="text"
             defaultValue={this.state.displayName}
             placeholder={this.state.displayName}
             minLength="3"
             maxLength="15"/>
          <button
            onClick={this.updateDisplayName}
            className='btn btn--primary btn--md'>
            <span>{contentStrings.displayNameModal.button}</span>
          </button>
          <p className='cancel'>{contentStrings.displayNameModal.cancel}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    }
    </div>
    )
  }
}

export default DisplayNameModal
```

Answer (score 1):

Whyt this:

```
props.displayNameModalActive
```

and not this:

```
this.props.displayNameModalActive
```

?

Correct me if I'm wrong but `render` doesn't get `props` as argument.

Comment: Ah, yep. That takes care of the error, but the modal overlay shows on page load (and not allowing the user to trigger it), but the modal itself isn't being rendered to the DOM. It renders
 `<div class="modal-container"><div></div></div>`